# own defined caption style works differently with same set by \captionsetup

Tags: captions

**Q1:** I think the following two examples should have the same typeset because the style content by `\DeclareCaptionStyle` is the same as the set by `\captionsetup`. But the real typeset (please see the attached figure) shows that the horizontal positions of these two captions are different. Why?

**Q2:** Though I set `format=hang`, the second line of the caption text lost the hanged effect. How can I get a `hanged & centering` caption?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,pifont}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{tt}{
    format=hang,justification=raggedright
}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Example 1:
\captionsetup[table]{
  format=hang,justification=raggedright
}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{This is a table\\second line}
  A table
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\vskip3cm
Example 2:
\captionsetup[table]{style=tt}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{This is a table\\second line}
  A table
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the first example, you're modifying the default style; in the second you're using a different style not based on the default. With `\DeclareCaptionStyle{tt}{style=default,format=hang,justification=raggedright}`, they'll match. I don't think the package expects manual line breaks in captions. If you do `\caption{A really long caption that is so long it needs to have have its lines break to fit}`, then you'll get the hanging style. If you need something like hanging style w/ manual line breaks, I'm not sure: `\caption{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}This is a table\\second line\end{tabular}}`?

Comment: But someone might have a better idea...

Comment: I suspect that hang and centered are both implemented using conflicting definition of \leftskip.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really improve on the frabjous ides (other than bug fixes).  I did figure out how to implement it with `\DeclareCaptionTextFormat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{myform}{\def\BODY{#1}\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\BODY\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{textformat=myform}
\caption[unformattted title]{This is a table\\second line}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses `\leftskip` and `\vtop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myform}{\vtop{%
  \sbox0{\textbf{#1#2}}%
  \centering
  \advance\leftskip by \wd0
  \hspace{-\wd0}\usebox0#3}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{format=myform}
\caption[unformatted title]{This is a table\\second line}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```